# Spring with Hibernate Error - Beginner Level

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to
>   in.codejava.spring.withHibernate.customer.dao.impl.HibCustomer at
>   in.codejava.spring.withHibernate.App.main(App.java:15)

This is the line from my code:

```
ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
HibCustomer CustomerDao = (HibCustomer) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
```

What could be the error?

Comment: Your session factory is set to `SessionFactoryImpl` by Hibernate.
Try to set int to  `HibCustomer` if it's a valid session factory implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is very likely that object by name "sessionFactory" is not instance of HibCustomer. In your case it is obvious, just look the stack trace. It tells you that you cannot cast instance of *org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl* to *in.codejava.spring.withHibernate.customer.dao.impl.HibCustomer.*

Most likely you want to cast it to the SessionFactory and continue from there:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
...
SessionFactory CustomerDao = (SessionFactory) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
```